# How to prove that if $S_2$ is linearly independent then $S_1$ is also linearly independent, where $S_2$ is superset of $S_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Ok, so this is my attempt to prove.

Let $S_2$ be linearly independent (L.I)

This implies that $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2+ \dots + a_n = 0$ if $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = 0$

Now assume that $S_1$ is linearly dependent (L.D)

This implies that

$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \dots + a_n v_n = 0$ for some non-zero scalars.

Then, $v_1 = -(a_2/a_1)v_2 - \dots - (a_n/a_1)v_n$

This implies that $v_1$ is L.D

Now, since $S_1$ is subset of $S_2$
implies that $v_1$ belongs to $S_2$.
But $S_2$ is L.I

Therefore, our assumption that $S_1$ is L.D wrong.

This implies that $S_1$ is L.I

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset formulas in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The idea feels right, but be careful. Note that you wrote

> This implies that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+......+a_nv_n=0$ if
> $a_1=a_2=....=a_n=0$,

but that's obvious.

If $S_2$ is L.I, what you can deduce is that **IF** $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+......+a_nv_n=0$, **THEN** $a_1=a_2=....=a_n=0$. Don't mess up with necessity/sufficiency.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Just to clarify. You prove it by proving the converse. If $S_1$ is L.D., then it has some trivial linear combination with non-null scalars. That's also a fair trivial linear combination with non-null scalars for $S_2$ (put null scalars on those vectors of $S_2$ that do not belong to $S_1$). Then you deduce $S_2$ is also L.D.

Comment: Good answer, +1.